# How can slicing dataset in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice

I want slicing dataset in `tf.data`. My data is like this:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                                              [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                                              [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                                              [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                                              [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Then the main data is:

```
[0 1 2 3 4]
[1 2 3 4 5]
[2 3 4 5 6]
[3 4 5 6 7]
[4 5 6 7 8]
```

I want create other tensor dataset that contain data like this:

```
       [[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4],
       [4, 5],
       [5, 6]]
```

In the numpy it is like this:

```
dataset[:,1:3]
```

How can do this in TensorFlow?

**Update:**

I do that with this:

```
dataset2 = dataset.map(lambda data: data[1:3])
for val in dataset2:
    print(val.numpy())
```

But I think there is good solutions.

Answer (score 1):

According to me your solution is a best solution. For the benefit of community, i am using [as_numpy_iterator()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#as_numpy_iterator) method of `tf.data.Dataset` to slice dataset (*small syntax change to your code*).

Please refer code below

```
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                                              [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                                              [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                                              [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                                              [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])


dataset2 = dataset.map(lambda data: data[1:3])
for val in dataset2.as_numpy_iterator():
    print(val)
```

Output:

```
[1 2]
[2 3]
[3 4]
[4 5]
[5 6]
```