# How can I divide a Tensorflow dataset created from ListFromFiles into train, validation and test sets?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a directory with files I want to split into train, validation and test sets. The approach I've taken is:

```
# Defining the positive and negative paths
POS = os.path.join("*.txt")

# Create positive Dataset
pos = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(POS)
```

If I try:

```
pos[3]
```

I get:

```
TypeError: '_ShuffleDataset' object is not subscriptable
```

I had thought to split using `take` & `skip` - e.g.

```
train = pos.take(10)
valid = pos.skip(10).take(5)
test = pos.skip(15).take(5)
```

But, when I try the following test, in a sample dir with 10 text files (a-j):

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf 

# Defining the positive and negative paths
POS = os.path.join("*.txt")

# Creating the Datasets
pos = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(POS)#.shuffle(len(POS))

for _ in range(20):
    for x in pos.take(1):
       print(x)
```

I get this output:

```
tf.Tensor(b'./c.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./g.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./g.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./c.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./g.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./b.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./g.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./c.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./g.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./c.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./h.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./e.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./c.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./f.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./f.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./h.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./i.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./b.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./j.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'./d.txt', shape=(), dtype=string)
```

Since there are only 10 txt files in the dir, I expected to see either the same output 20x, a list of 10 distinct files followed by a crash, or 2 lists of 10 distinct files.   Instead, `take` seems to be working off of a fresh list each time. So, my idea of using `skip` and `take` will likely end up with overlap among my sets.

The only thing I can think to do is split up the file lists before creating the Dataset. But, there must be *some* way to get slices from a dataset. The approach from [Slicing TF Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63429746/how-can-slicing-dataset-in-tensorflow) didn't work for me. I didn't see anything in the documentation on `take`.

Comment: From TF docs: Note: The default behavior of this method is to return filenames in a non-deterministic random shuffled order. Pass a seed or shuffle=False to get results in a deterministic order --> https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#list_files